# Grails remote-pagination is refreshing entire page instead of div

Tags: grails, plugins, pagination

I am having problems with the grails plugin remote-pagination.  I have created a new project and copy pasted the sample code for the plugin.  There is a book class that has a list view and a template for the table.  The pagination is supposed to update only the data in the div 'filteredList', but instead the page is refreshed with the layout view, _filtered.gsp, only.  Below is the code :

Controller:

```
class BookController {
def scaffold = true

def list = {
    [bookInstanceList: Book.list(max:10,offset: 0), bookInstanceTotal: Book.count()]
}

def filter = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    render(template: 'filter', model: [bookInstanceList: Book.list(params), bookInstanceTotal: Book.count()])
}
```

}

list.gsp - view :

```
<%@ page import="com.intelligrape.Book" %>
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book')}"/>
    <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]"/></title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="nav">
    <span class="menuButton"><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a>
    </span>
    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]"/></g:link></span>
</div>

<div class="body">
    <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]"/></h1>
    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
    </g:if>
    <div id="filteredList">
        <g:render template="filter"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

_filtered.gsp - template for table of books

```
    <div>
<div class="list">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <util:remoteSortableColumn property="id" title="${message(code: 'book.id.label', default: 'Id')}" update="filteredList" action="filter"/>

        <util:remoteSortableColumn property="author" title="${message(code: 'book.author.label', default: 'Author')}" update="filteredList" action="filter"/>

        <util:remoteSortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'book.name.label', default: 'Name')}" update="filteredList" action="filter" max="5"/>

        <util:remoteSortableColumn property="price" title="${message(code: 'book.price.label', default: 'Price')}" update="filteredList" action="filter"/>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${bookInstanceList}" status="i" var="bookInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

            <td><g:link action="show" id="${bookInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "id")}</g:link></td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "author")}</td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "name")}</td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "price")}</td>

        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="paginateButtons">
    <util:remotePaginate total="${bookInstanceTotal}" update="filteredList"     action="filter" pageSizes="[5: '5 on Page',10:'10 on Page',15:'15 on Page']" max="5" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to add the javascript library tag in the header section of the list.gsp page :

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
```

Comment: Well, it does work, but then breaks my selection of `max` items. Did you have that problem?

Comment: No this was not an issue for me.  The above fixed my initial problem.